# Looping through multiple JObject levels and gathering information as a string

Tags: c#, json, foreach

I'm using the following code to gather Json data from a URL.

```
            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/id/tryhardhusky/inventory/json/753/6");
            JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
            JObject ja = (JObject)jo["rgDescriptions"];

            int cCount = 0;
            int bCount = 0;
            int eCount = 0;

            foreach(var x in ja){

                // I'm stuck here.
                string type = (Object)x["type"];

            }

            CUAI.sendMessage("I found: " + ja.Count.ToString());
```

Everything is working well until I get to the foreach statement.
Here is a snippet of the JSON Data.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "rgInventory": {
        "Blah other stuff"
    },
    "rgDescriptions": {
        "637390365_0": {
            "appid": "753",
            "background_color": "",
            "type": "0RBITALIS Trading Card"
        "175240190_0": {
            "appid": "753",
            "background_color": "",
            "type": "Awesomenauts Trading Card"
        },
        "195930139_0": {
            "appid": "753",
            "background_color": "",
            "type": "CONSORTIUM Emoticon"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wanting to loop through each item in rgDescriptions and get the `type` data as a string, Then check if it contains either `background`, `emoticon` or `trading card`.
I know I can use the `if(type.Contains("background"))` to check what the item type is, But I'm having trouble with the foreach loop.

If I use `foreach(JObject x in ja)` I get a `cannot convert type` Error.
If I use `foreach(Object x in ja)` It comes up with a `Cannot apply indexing of type object`.
This error also happens when I use `foreach(var x in ja)` and `string type = (JObject)x["type"];`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, Please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some errors in your JSON. Check it with jsonlint.com. I think it should look something like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "rgInventory": {
        "Blah other stuff": ""
    },
    "rgDescriptions": {
        "637390365_0": {
            "appid": "753",
            "background_color": "",
            "type": "0RBITALIS Trading Card"
        },
        "175240190_0": {
            "appid": "753",
            "background_color": "",
            "type": "Awesomenauts Trading Card"
        },
        "195930139_0": {
            "appid": "753",
            "background_color": "",
            "type": "CONSORTIUM Emoticon"
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the JProperty, JToken and the SelectToken Method to get the type:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://steamcommunity.com/id/tryhardhusky/inventory/json/753/6");
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (JProperty x in jo.SelectToken("rgDescriptions"))
{
    JToken type = x.Value.SelectToken("type");
    string typeStr = type.ToString().ToLower();

    if (typeStr.Contains("background"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contains 'background'");
    }
    if (typeStr.Contains("emoticon"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contains 'emoticon'");
    }
    if (typeStr.Contains("trading card"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contains 'trading card'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to `SelectToken`! Ill have to read up more about using this. Also, Huge thanks for the help. Code is working perfectly. :)